# Flutter: Difference between import and library

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know it is a good question or not but I want to know what is differense between importing this library

`import 'package:hw_mp/hw_mp.dart';`

with

`library peg_parser.source_scanner;`.

Seems both are library but what is differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the `library peft_parser.source_scanner` does *not* import anything.
It declares the name of the *current* library.

Library names are not very important in Dart. The only place you can refer to a library by name is in its own part files, and you can also just refer to it by URL there.
The only things a Dart library names is good for is avoiding accidentally importing the same library twice, using different URLs. If that happens, the compiler will treat it as two different libraries, declaring different types with the same name, which is bad.
However, it will warn you if you have two different libraries with the same name.

Comment: `peft_parser.source_scanner` is a simple class or a function ? Or how can i make it ? What should I look to more information? @irn

Comment: `peft_parser.source_scanner` is just a name. It's an identifier sequence and it's the declared name of the library. There is not a lot of documentation about the `library` declaration because it's not very necessary. It used to be more important (it was required if you used parts: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package), but these days most people simply omit the declaration and leave their library unnamed.